# Is it possible to use Regex to add a line into a specific group of lines in a file?

Tags: regex

For example if i had in a file something like:

```
<Word />


</Word>
```

Would it be possible with regex to add a line in between Word and Word? Like:

```
 <Word />
 hello
 </Word>
```

Or would I need to use a different method to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a *lot* easier to 1) find the first line, 2) find the second line, 3) insert a line in the middle?  Why do you think regex is applicable here?

Comment: yes you can, just use groups [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnyPVt/1)

Comment: Yes, but what regex tools/programming language, environment, file type are you doing this in?

Comment: @Amy regular expressions are a very efficient way to search text and provide easy substitution/insertion, how would regex *not* be applicable here?

Comment: @WillBarnwell I am perfectly aware of the capabilities and purpose of regex, as well as their limitations.  Many beginners look at regex like a panacea, which it is not.  Asking the OP to why they want to use regex is perfectly reasonable.  If he can articulate his reasons, great.  If not, we can steer him toward a more applicable tool.  All too frequently, using regex to solve a problem leaves you with two problems.  I would like to make sure regex is the right tool for this job, and to do that, I asked the OP a question.  Using regex for the sake of using regex is not beneficial.

Comment: Okay, I agree that a lot of questions coming through this tag deserve a frame challenge of "Why regex?" I had chosen to find out more about the details of OPs problem before deciding if I would recommend a different approach. The markdown-looking tags make me suspect that regex may not be the best tool, but without details, I was not sure enough to yet diagnose and address an XY problem. Thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex itself proves its power only with a tool or programming language.

Use Regex to capture these 2 lines you want to insert a new one in between using the capturing groups `()` and the variables referring to these, ex. `$1`, `$2` etc.

1. Capture the 2 lines. Don't forget to capture the new line (`\n`) within the first line.

   ```
   (line1\n)(line2)
   ```
2. Use groups to enter the new line in between. Again mind the new line (`\n`):

   ```
   $1hello\n$2
   ```

See the working demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Jlpozh/1).

Don't expect this insertion to be permanent unless you perform and save these changes on any advanced text editor (Notepad++ or SublimeText or PSPad etc...). Or use a programming language to read the file, extract the text using the Regex above and insert the desired line and write to the same file.